# Get the value of each XML node and set it to a parameter

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

How to set a parameter in each XML nodes using SQL Server 2008?

I am new with SQL and I have XML data like this

```
Set @xml='<root><name>John </name><age>8</age></root>'
```

I need to set the value of node `<name>`, `<age>` in a parameter. For example:

```
Set @name='get value of node <name>'
Set @age='the value of <age>'
```

Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: You want to substitute any instance of `<name>` and `<age>` in several strings, by the respective element values in an XML stored in a variable... Correct? Or, do you want to get the element values of *any* element in the XML, and substitute *any* occurance of those tags in those strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get this correctly you are getting parameters within an XML as *key-value-pairs*. What you try to achieve is to read the value into the fitting variable. Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML;
SET @xml='<root><name>John </name><age>8</age></root>';

DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @age INT;

SET @name=@xml.value('(/root/name)[1]','nvarchar(max)');
SET @age =@xml.value('(/root/age)[1]','int');

SELECT @name,@age;
```

If you'd need to query the values from a variable name, you can use this:

```
DECLARE @nodeName NVARCHAR(100)='name';
SET @name=@xml.value('(/root/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@nodeName")])[1]','nvarchar(max)');
```

The central idea is to use an `XQuery`-expression `(/root/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@nodeName")])[1]` to pick *the first node's value, where the element's name is like the given parameter*

Comment: *"I need to set the value of node <name>, <age> in a parameter*", those parameters I think he's referring to the `@name` and `@age` variables. I read it as: replace each occurance of `<name>` and `<age>` in a variable by the element's value in the XML. I could be wrong though.

Comment: @TT. Well, I don't know... The sentence you refer to looks to me like *I want to read the value from `<name>` or `<age>` and shuffle it into a variable*. I took this *Set @name='get value of node <name>'* the way I put it above... We'll see :-)

Comment: Yeah indeed, it can be interpreted in both ways.

Comment: Side note: wouldn't it be easier to select the value of `(/root/name)[1]` etc? I mean less text :)

Comment: @TT. You are absolutely right... Had in mind, that the node's name might be passed in generically. But in in this case all node names would be known... I'll edit my answer, thx!

Comment: @userMJ I'm glad to read this! Please allow me one hint: If this works for you, it would be kind to tick the acceptance check (an outlined check symbol besides the votes counter) to mark this question as solved. Thx!